# Revisions in track changes: Send as doc or pdf?

Tags: paper-submission, formatting

I'm in the social sciences and received a revise decision for my first submitted paper. The editors said that revisions can be done via the track changes mode in MS Word or by using bold or coloured text.

I did all my revisions in track changes but am now unsure if I should submit my revisions as a Word doc or a pdf. Both seem fine for the journal, but I'd be interested in what the standard procedure is.

Also, if I submit a doc, should the page numbers in my response to the reviewers refer to the "Simple Markup" or "All Markup" version of the document?

Thanks!

Comment: You should ask them. There isn't a general answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Not a big deal, they can surely handle whatever you send**

The only thing to do is, if/when your paper is accepted, include something that's editable - so make sure you have the source files uploaded.